# Foto de datagridview a Picturebox

Tags: mysql, c#, visual-studio, datagrid, picturebox

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, como cargo una imagen al dar clic en datagridview y que muestre la imagen en un picturebox, yo cargo la imagen con la ruta del directorio donde se encuentra la imagen así:

```
private void btnPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog searchImage = new OpenFileDialog();
        searchImage.Filter = "Archivos de imagen(*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png";
        searchImage.FileName = "";
        searchImage.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\source\\repos\\Lab4_Grupo2\\Lab4_Grupo2\\obj\\resource\\animals\\";
        if (searchImage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtRoute.Text = searchImage.FileName;
            pctPic.ImageLocation = searchImage.FileName;
            pctPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
```

Con este botón guardo los datos (en el txtRoute.Text se guarda la ruta de la imagen y es la que se envia a la BD):

```
        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName.Text == "" || cmbAnimal.Text == "" || txtRace.Text == "" || dtpDate.Text == "" || txtowner.Text == "" || rtxObs.Text == "" || cmbType.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, complete los campos solicitados", "¡AVISO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            txtName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            db.setAdd(txtName.Text, cmbAnimal.Text, txtRace.Text, dtpDate.Value, txtowner.Text, cmbType.Text, Convert.ToDouble(nudPre.Value), rtxObs.Text, txtRoute.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado correctamente.", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Clear();
        }
    }
```

Y este método tengo de insert en una clase

```
        public void setAdd(string nombre, string animal, string raza, DateTime fecha, string dueño, string tipo_c, double precio, string desc_c, string foto)
    {
        cn.Insert("INSERT INTO consulta(Nombre, Animal, Raza, Fecha, duenho, Tipo_Consulta, Precio, Descripcion, foto)" +
            "values('" + nombre + "', '" + animal + "','" + raza + "','" + fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "','" + dueño + "','" + tipo_c + "'," + precio + ",'" +  desc_c + "','" + foto + "')");
    }
```

Me podrían ayudar, por favor, y decirme si es buena opción guardar la imagen con la ruta o como sería mejorar, para al consultarla aparezca en un picturebox, de antemano gracias

Comment: @Japv se me olvidaba, es un CRUD completo, aquí está el código en donde hago para guardar la ruta de la foto:   
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                db.setAdd(txtName.Text, cmbAnimal.Text, txtRace.Text, dtpDate.Value, txtowner.Text, cmbType.Text, Convert.ToDouble(nudPre.Value), rtxObs.Text, txtRoute.Text);
                MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado correctamente.", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Clear();
            } `

Comment: @Japv gracias por tu sugerencia ya la corregí, espero se entienda...

Comment: Ya te respondí dime si te sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar la imagen en el picturebox pon esto

```
pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(searchImage.FileName);
```

Esto va dentro del if en que muestras al openfiledialog

Lo que hace este código es cargar la imagen que seleccionas a través del openfiledialog.

Comment: Dime si te sirvio