# Definir variables para imagenes en C#

Tags: c#, oracle-11g, blob

Amigos, quisiera realizar una consulta sobre como puedo definir una variable para imagenes en las clases de mi proyecto en C#.

El destino es una base de datos oracle que guarda la imagen como BLOB.
Aqui les muestro un pequeño ejemplo a lo que me refiero.

```
    public string CorreoTransportista { get; set; }
    public string RutTransportista { get; set; }
    public string NumeroLicencia { get; set; }
    public string TipoLicencia { get; set; }
    public "    " FotoPersonal { get; set; }
```

Con que tipo puedo llenar el espacio en blanco?
No se si con la información entregada es posible otorgar una respuesta o si necesitan más información, ya que he buscado en google y aun no he podido encontrar la solución.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Para estos casos, lo que se hace es guardar la URL donde se guardara la imagen. Me imagino que el la base de datos tienes creado una columna de tipo varchar que seria tu campo "foto", por lo que ese campo tiene que ser string. Ahora, la imagen en si que te llega, debe ser byte[]

Comment: necesitarías un "byte[]" array si en tu base de datos es un blob, necesitarias convertir la imagen a un arreglo de bytes primero

Comment: Revisa estos links, quizas puedan ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426998/como-insertar-una-imagen-en-bytes-a-la-base-de-datos/427043#427043 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410434/foto-de-datagridview-a-picturebox/410611#410611